# Changing pixel values in of a 50x50 square 2d numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, image-processing

Doing a bit of image processing in python and I am trying to change the value of a 50x50 square of numpy array and each square would change every 200 pixels. So far this is what I have:

```
 image_data[0::200,0::200] = 999
```

This plants an extremely bright pixel every 200 spaces. I, however, cannot figure out how to get the pixels surrounding it to change. I tried something similar to this:

```
image_data[0::200+1,0::200] = 999
image_data[0::200-1,0::200] = 999
image_data[0::200+2,0::200] = 999
image_data[0::200-2,0::200] = 999
```

But this spreads the pixels out over iterations. I am somewhat rusty with python and the solution is probably trivial, but I appreciate any help I can get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like that:

```
import numpy as np
image_data=np.zeros([1017,1017])
places=np.arange(-25,26)
centers=np.array([[200*i]*len(places) for i in range(1,len(image_data)//200+1)])
index_list=np.concatenate(centers+places)
index_list=index_list[index_list<len(image_data)]
image_data[np.ix_(index_list,index_list)]=999
```

The line `image_data=np.zeros([1000,1000])` just initializes the matrix for the example above, you can use your matrix instead. `index_list` is a list of all relevant row and column indices.

`image_data[np.ix_(index_list,index_list)]=999` assigns 999 to the relevant part of the matrix. 
Note that I set `places=np.arange(-25,26)` because it seems that you wanted 50-by-50 square inclusive (that is, lines 175-225 including endpoints and so on). If that is not the case you can just change 26 to 25, or to set it any way you like.

Also, this code is for square matrix `image_data`. If it is rectangular, then you should define rows and columns indices separately, like that:

```
import numpy as np
image_data=np.zeros([1017,2017])
places=np.arange(-25,26)
centers_rows=np.array([[200*i]*len(places) for i in range(1,len(image_data)//200+1)])
centers_columns=np.array([[200*i]*len(places) for i in range(1,len(image_data[0])//200+1)])
row_index=np.concatenate(centers_rows+places)
col_index=np.concatenate(centers_columns+places)
row_index=row_index[row_index<len(image_data)]
col_index=col_index[col_index<len(image_data[0])]
image_data[np.ix_(row_index,col_index)]=999
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. How would you approach this if you needed lets say 50 pixels surround every 200th pixel changed. Like roughly 175-225 in both row and columns all at 999 brightness

Comment: I updated the code to cover the case in which image_data is rectangular as well.

Comment: If I wanted to adjust the brightness of each square kernel based on a Gaussian function, is there a quick fix for this? If I attach a gaussian in the place of 999 it creates one at the center of the image, not at the center of each square.

Comment: If you try to substitute not just a number, you need to make sure that the dimensions fit. For example, this would work : image_data[np.ix_(row_index,col_index)]=np.random.randint(5,size=(len(row_index),len(col_index))). So you can try to prepare beforehand the matrix that you want to substitute, and then substitute it.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest a simple approach using `arr.flatten()` and `np.reshape()`

```
In [140]: a = np.zeros((1000, 1000))

# C style flattening for row level operation
In [141]: af = a.flatten()
In [142]: af.shape
Out[142]: (1000000,)

# get every 200th element
In [145]: idxs = [ idx for idx, el in enumerate(af) if idx % 200 == 0]

# generate required indices
In [146]: indices = [ range(el-25, el+25) for el in idxs[1:]]

# update new values to the above indices
In [147]: af[indices] = 999

# now, again reshape to original shape
In [148]: a_modified = af.reshape((1000, 1000))


# Fortran style flattening for column level operation
In [149]: amf = a_modified.flatten('F')

# get every 200th element
In [150]: idxs = [idx for idx, el in enumerate(amf) if idx % 200 == 0]

# generate required indices
In [151]: indices = [ range(el-25, el+25) for el in idxs[1:]]

# update new values to the above indices
In [152]: amf[indices] = 999

# now, again reshape to original shape
In [153]: a_final = amf.reshape((1000, 1000))
```

Now, irrespective of the shape of the image (square, rectangular), this approach would work.